# can't run jdk-8u202-windows-x64.exe ... nothing happens ... what do I do?

Tags: java

I'm supposed to install JDK and JRE 8.

I tried running file I downloaded from Oracle:

**jdk-8u202-windows-x64.exe**

When I try running it, nothing happens, no errors, *nothing*.

I tried running it as Admin... same thing.

I fired up the task manager and tried again. I never saw it running in the task manager, even briefly.

My computer is running Windows 10 Enterprise 64 bit dual core.

Any idea why this would happen?  I'm stumped!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my desktop computer did not have its permissions elevated enough to do this operation. Sadly, no error messages of any kind were displayed.

**Running as 'Admin**' was not good enough! I had to open a ticket with our internal help desk to get my permissions temporarily elevated. Once this occurred, I was able to run the installer without any problems! Yay!

If you are *not* allowed to do this, chances are the corporate policy where you are at will not allow you to elevate the permissions on your machine... so you will be out of luck.  ... They do have their reasons.

Hopefully its just a matter of opening a ticket in your organization, and a little while later you will be able to run the installer just fine!

A final word:  Most programs/installers that you try to run where you do not have permission will display some sort of error dialog to that effect. Thus, you know where you stand. With *this* JDK installer, there are no messages. You are left completely in the dark. Bottom line: your user profile on that machine does not have the proper permissions. If you get those elevated permissions it will work.

Oh, btw, after I was given the permissions, I needed to restart the computer for them to take effect.